# Did lord Shri Ram, Laxman and Sita ever face dangerous wild animals during their exile in forests?

Tags: scripture, ramayana, rama, animals

During lord Rama's exile period they killed many Asuras. And sometimes I assume that, In jungle or forest wild animals like lions, tigers,bears and others would also be present there.

Did they ever face them? If they did many times then what were the behaviours or actions of the wild animals when they face lord Rama, Laxman and Sita mata. And how did lord Rama treat them?

Comment: Since Rama and Lakshmana were strong warriors that too with mathra knowledge, driving away if required killing hostile/nuisance animals would have been too easy for them so it may not be worth  mentioning in the Ramayana.  Real danger was from maya Rakshasas like Kakasura, Maricha, Ravana